# pymongo get id for collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

i have this code:

```
def get_attribute_colour(colour_code):
    attribute_colour_meta = db.attributes.aggregate([{ '$match': {"name.en-UK": "Colour"} },
        { '$unwind' : "$values" },
        { '$project': { "code" : "$values.code", "valueId": "$values._id"} },
        { '$match': {"code": colour_code} }])

    return attribute_colour_meta['result']
```

that looks up a collection called attributes, which has the following structure:

```
> db.attributes.find({}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e00"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "code" : "AQ",
            "pmsCode" : "638c",
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "Aqua"
            },
            "tcxCode" : "16-4529 TCX",
            "hexCode" : "#00aed8",
            "images" : [
                "AQ.jpg"
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996d83")
        },
        {
            "code" : "AQ",
            "pmsCode" : "3115c",
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "Aqua"
            },
            "tcxCode" : "",
            "hexCode" : "#00c4db",
            "images" : [
                "AQ.jpg"
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996d84")
        },
.....
        }
    ],
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "Colour"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e1b"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "code" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e01"),
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "0-3 MTHS"
            }
        },
.....
        }
    ],
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "Size"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e28"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "Currency" : "GBP",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e1c"),
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "Carton price list"
            }
        },
        }
    ],
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "Price list"
    }
}
>
```

basically, there are 3 attributes, `colour`, `size` and `price list`, each of which has sub-documents called `values`

in my `def get_attribute_colour` function, how do i return the `_id` for the attribute within the results, so that i get something like:

```
    { attributeId: ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996e00"), 
    valueId: ObjectId("53b27bded901f26432996d83") }
```

the result does return the _id:

```
[{u'code': u'AQ', u'_id': ObjectId('53b27bded901f26432996e00'), u'valueId': ObjectId('53b27bded901f26432996d83')}]
```

but i don't see where this is specified?

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The valueId is the attributeId for the matched colour_code. The `_id` is the document `_id` and of course "code" is the matched code value. So really not sure what you are asking other than "how does this code work?"

Comment: so basically the `_id` is added by default, as i did not specified it in `{ '$project': { "code" : "$values.code", "valueId": "$values._id"} },` ? As from my understanding is that `$project` is similar to MySQL `SELECT id, code FROM table; ` where `$project` are the fields you want to get values for?

Comment: It is happen with the unwind in the pipeline, Have you tried reordering the aggregation functions in the pipline? Granted that may not work for what you are trying to achieve in terms of structure, but i think that is what is happening.